# Problem with Ubuntu Installation, Removed Windows by accident and can't boot into anything

Tags: partitioning, windows, delete

I think I have deleted my windows OS while installing ubuntu , i meant to do a dual install but while doing this i messed up my partition wiping my whole hard drive clean. i was not able to boot any OS it just came up with a error. i was able to use the ubuntu live CD to get onto my hardrive there was nothing there my laptop wouldn't allow me to install ubuntu ether but after i was able to partition my drive so i could install ubuntu but still it will not allow me to install windows . I don't know much but i think i have to re-partition
my drive so it will allow me to install windows again. i have another feeling its because i don't have the service packs needed to install windows 7 but ubuntu will not allow me to install these ether.

Ps. while installing Ubuntu I clicked the make space option while installing

a link to a video showing what i mean - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuYX1la1ngs&feature=plcp

Comment: Do you have a windows install cd or factory restore disk? If you do, your best bet is to install windows first, and let it use the entire disk at its will. Once that is installed it should let you install the service packs, etc, however you may have fun activating it again, and may have to phone MS to tell them to reactivate you key or whatever. Once windows is installed install Ubuntu again, and there should be an option 'install alongside windows' or something similar. This should take care of everything for you.

Comment: i dont have a restore cd i just want to re-install windows through ubuntu if possible

Answer (score 1):

Paul, I believe your best way out here is to install Windows first after formatting the complete disk. While installing Windows make sure that you create atleast two partitions, one on which your Windows OS will run and the other on which you will install Ubuntu.

Once this is done, use the Ubuntu cd to install your Ubuntu OS on the partition that is not holding your Windows installation. Make sure you choose the custom option when the partitioning schemes are displayed. Hope this helps your cause.